# Is it possible to create a slack notification channel using GKE's config connector?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-config-connector

I'm trying to use the GKE config connector to create my log based metrics, alert policies, etc.
I'm stuck on how to create a slack notification `MonitoringNotificationChannel`.

I can see *how* the format should be done from here: https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/monitoring/monitoringnotificationchannel#basicauth_webhook_monitoring_notification_channel
(and from the https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.notificationChannelDescriptors/list API)

```
{
      "type": "slack",
      "displayName": "Slack",
      "description": "A channel that sends notifications to the third-party chat service [Slack](https://slack.com, \"Slack web site\").",
      "labels": [
        {
          "key": "auth_token",
          "description": "A permanent authentication token provided by Slack. This field is obfuscated by returning only a few characters of the key when fetched."
        },
        {
          "key": "channel_name",
          "description": "The Slack channel to which to post notifications."
        }
      ],
      "name": "projects/as-dashboard-213905/notificationChannelDescriptors/slack",
      "launchStage": "GA"
    }
```

Something like that

```
apiVersion: monitoring.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: MonitoringNotificationChannel
metadata:
  name: slack-notification
spec:
  type: slack
  labels:
    channelName: my-slack-channel
  description: Sends notifications to slack channe;
  sensitiveLabels:
    authToken:
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: password
          name: slack-auth-token
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the actual auth token to put into a kube secret... From doing it via the UI, I'm assuming that the app token is generated as part of the initial connection, and then provided directly from the Slack Google Cloud Monitoring app to GCP itself.
But how do *I* get that API token for reuse?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Store your incoming webhook URL in Secret Manager:

1. Open the Secret Manager page in the Google Cloud console:
2. Click Create secret.
3. Enter a name for your secret.
4. Under Secret value, add your incoming webhook URL for your Slack
   app.
5. To save your secret, click Create secret.

You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-slack) for reference. I hope this answers your concern.

Comment: nah I'm trying to figure out *how* to get the auth token. once I have the token, that's easy. but I can't figure out how to get it. Slack doesn't give you a way to do it without creating an app, but that's also a lot more work than I'd want to do...